# query for one field doesn't equal another field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I query for, or filter for, one field doesn't equal another field?  i.e. where document1.city1.name not equal document1.city2.name.

Some version of this?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes , you will need to use script filter to achieve this

```
{
  "bool": {
    "filter": {
      "script": {
        "script": "doc['field1'].value !=  doc['field2'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html#query-dsl-script-filter)

Comment: Doesn't work with 6.3:  `"reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [filtered]."`

Comment: @chefarov - Filtered query is removed in later versions , use script query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html

Comment: Note that this is an "expensive" query since it can't do an indexed lookup. ES doesn't really offer feature parity with relational databases here.