# Kibana - join in the same index

Tags: sql, join, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-query

I have the most basic knowledge in Kibana, and perhaps just a little bit more of Elasticsearch. Is this possible to build a query which will return all items where field_A == field_B? In sql world, it would be something like:
`select * from MyTalbe as t1 inner join MyTable as t2 on t1.field_A = t2.field_B` ?

Comment: I don't believe you can easily do this in kibana.  Even with a raw ES query I'm not sure how you'd do it.

Comment: In ElasticSearch you can do that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845052/query-for-one-field-doesnt-equal-another-field-in-elasticsearch