# Elasticsearch DSL query finding irrelevant results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using Elasticsearch to search the Packetbeat indices to identify if two IP addresses communicate. If IP xx.xx.xx.xx talks to IP yy.yy.yy.yy OR if IP yy.yy.yy.yy talk to IP xx.xx.xx.xx, I want to know about it. Below is my DSL but all the returned results are not relevant at all. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
GET /packetbeat-*/_search?size=100&pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_type": "flow"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "source.ip": "127.0.0.1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "dest.ip": "127.0.0.1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": "flow"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "source.ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "dest.ip": "yy.yy.yy.yy"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": "flow"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "source.ip": "yy.yy.yy.yy"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "dest.ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-30d/d",
            "lte": "now-1d/d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your query:

1. `_type: flow`
2. not localhost
3. `source.ip != dest.ip`
4. source.ip OR dest.ip equal to IP_X OR IP_Y

Have a look, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28847851/2069294):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_type": "flow"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['source.ip'].value != doc['dest.ip'].value"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "source.ip": [
              "IP_X",
              "IP_Y"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "dest.ip": [
              "IP_X",
              "IP_Y"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "source.ip": "127.0.0.1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "dest.ip": "127.0.0.1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-30d/d",
            "lte": "now-1d/d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I do have specific IP addresses to search for. The xx.xx.xx.xx and yy.yy.yy.yy are actually known IP addresses I was told to use to search for communication between them. I think I am not doing something right in the "must" and "should" but not sure what. If I break up my "should" into two separate DSL queries, it works. Just not when I combine them into a "should"