# Filter values by values of another field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to know how I can filter values of field by values of another field, for example:

this is mappings

```json
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "testArr": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "testArr2": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The document:

```json
PUT /test/_doc/1
{
  "testArr": ["1", "2", "3"],
  "testArr2": ["2"]
}
```

How I can return **for field `testArr` only values that aren't present in field `testArr2`**?
**as a result, I want to see something like this:**

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "testArr": ["1", "3"]
  }
}
```

what I tried:

```json
GET /test/_search
{
  "_source": "testArr",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "!doc['testArr2'].contains(doc['testArr'].value)",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

looks like it works, but it returns all values ["1", "2", "3"] and I need to have only a difference in result = ["1", "3"], not all values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [query for one field doesn't equal another field in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845052/query-for-one-field-doesnt-equal-another-field-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: While not exactly the same, I think the question above solves almost exactly the same problem as you're facing.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work as far as script query, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

for those who will search the answer, I found the solution in **script_fields**:

```json
GET /test/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "filtered": {
      "script": {
        "source": "ArrayList result = []; for(Object v:doc['testArr']) { if(!doc['testArr2'].contains(v)) { result.add(v); } } return result;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```